# How to know if a field is an array in elasticsearch?

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I would like to know which field are array in my index in ES 6.8.3.

When I retrieve the mapping of the index via Kibana API :

```
GET structured_data/_mapping
```

I only get the kind of the value within the array.

It is a problem because when I want to load the data from spark, if there is an array field, I need to specify it otherwise it will raise an error.

Thanks in advance,

Louis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no dedicated data type `array` in Elasticsearch. Look at this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html)      you don't have to specify anything specific in the mapping to store an array of values. Look in your source data if that contains an array, ES should take that array, given all the data inside that array is same data type

Comment: Thank you ! So I guess I won't be able to know if a field from an index is an array without loading a small data sample ...

Comment: In case of we have such situation like: 


    <field1> : ["value", "value"] ,
    <field2> : "value" 

How we can determine the difference between field 1 and field 2 ?